# Position object relative to camera in SceneView

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I've tried modifying the SceneForm example to position an object relative to the camera as soon as the scene is touched, but no objects appear. What am I missing? Checked the docs and YouTube videos to no avail. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Code below (in Kotlin):

```
arFragment!!.arSceneView.setOnTouchListener { view : View, event: MotionEvent ->
  println("Touch!")
  val andy = Node()
  andy.setParent(arFragment?.arSceneView?.scene?.camera)
  andy.localPosition = Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
  andy.renderable = andyRenderable
  true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, I think the local position is outside what is visible.  If the camera is 0,0,0 then forward one meter is 0,0,-1.  This worked for me.  Placing Andy in front of the camera:

```
      Node andy = new Node();
      andy.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera());
      andy.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0f,0,-1f));
      andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
how to add rotating animation to the modelRenderable(andy) in sceneview - android 

{
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            CompletableFuture<ViewRenderable> finalCouponLayout = couponLayout;
            CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable> finalAndy = andy;
            CompletableFuture.allOf(couponLayout, finalAndy)
                    .handle(
                            (notUsed, throwable) -> {

                                if (throwable != null) {
                                    return null;
                                }

                                try {
                                    // Non scalable info outside location
                                    ViewRenderable vr = finalCouponLayout.get();
                                    //
                                    ModelRenderable andyRenderable = finalAndy.get();
                                    //
                                    Node base = new Node();

                                    if (flag.equals("coin")) {

                                        base.setRenderable(andyRenderable);

                                    } else if (flag.equals("feeds")) {
                                        base.setRenderable(vr);
                                    }
                         }
}
```